# enable get bash here/get gui here on Windows

Tags: windows, git, bash

I'm trying to create a repository on Git for Windows and, after having installed Git, when I right click on a window which I'm trying to convert into a git repository, there is no option "get bash here" or "get gui here" that I've seen in other tutorials for Git for Windows. What can I do to enable these options to appear when I right-click on the particular folder?

Comment: Already answered on [same question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24387237/2963314