# "Open git bash here" and "Open command prompt here" disappeared from Windows explorer context menu

Tags: windows, git, bash, windows-7, windows-7-x64

Short of re-installing git or editing the relevant registry key that adds context menus to the shell myself, I was wondering if there was another way to bring back the "Git Bash Here" and "Open command window here" menus?

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a "open git-bash here..." context menu to the windows explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386657/how-to-add-a-open-git-bash-here-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer)

Comment: Nothing here explains why git-bash sometimes goes missing from the right click menu. Without knowing why it happens, how can we prevent it happening again? Google took me to another place to search for answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591955/git-bash-here-is-not-exisiting-in-windows-explorer-right-clickcontext-menu) and that has unfortunately disappeared!

Comment: FYI, if you are using Windows 11, there's a post created for that. You can track that availability there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237709/how-to-add-a-git-bash-here-context-menu-option-to-the-windows-explorer-in-wind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders/29769228#29769228) SO question:

> Context menu for **right click on folders in left panel** of Windows
>
> ### Explorer or on background of a directory in right panel:
>
> 1. **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell** if you are administrator
> 2. **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell**  if you are a normal user
>
> ---
>
> Context menu for **right click on folders in right panel** of Windows
>
> ### Explorer:
>
> 1. **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell** if you are administrator
> 2. **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\shell**  if you are a normal user
>
> ---
>
> ### Context menu for any file:
>
> 1. **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell** if you are administrator
> 2. **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell** if you are a normal user
>
> In all cases:
>
> 1. add a new key under "shell", naming it as you want to name the
>      context menu item
> 2. add a new key inside this key, named **command** (mandatory name)
> 3. edit    the "default" property in "command" to
>      **myprogrampath\path\path\executable.exe %1** to pass the file path and
>      name of the selected file to your custom program

**Update:**

So I did a little more research into where the actual git bash and git gui context menu items were stored in the registry. I exported the keys that I had in my registry into a `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git-gui.exe\" \"--working-dir\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\git_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%v.\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\git_gui\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git-gui.exe\" \"--working-dir\" \"%v.\""
```

Comment: To add, this script on git fixes it, no problem: https://github.com/Hattoff/GitBashHere

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer with the theory and the minimal example see the examples for Git (and not only) with user-friendly names, shortcut keys (& in a user-friendly name) and icons in the ["win-registry-snippets" repository](https://github.com/NickVeld/win-registry-snippets/blob/main/GitHere.reg)