# "Git bash here" and "Git GUI here" not working on Windows 10

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I just installed Git for Window version 2.18.0 64-bit on a new Windows 10 machine (Win 10 Enterprise).

When I right-click in explorer and choose 'Git Bash Here' or 'Git Gui Here' I see an 'Application Not Found' error pop up.

[image]

**Update**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386657/how-to-add-a-open-git-bash-here-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer) which *nearly* helped me find the problem and the solution.

With `regedit` I was able to see that the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell\command` was pointing to my user folder, instead of the actual location of git:

[image]

For "Git Bash Here", I changed the value to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-bash.exe" "--cd=%1"`

Similarly for "Git GUI here", I changed the value for the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui\command` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git-gui.exe" "--working-dir" "%1"`

However, I still see the 'Application Not Found' error. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but the answer didn't work so it's just something I tried. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Nvm...I thought you found the answer, but then put it in your question.

Comment: Hmm a downvote - I wonder why I got that? Would be interested to hear how I could improve the question.

Comment: I countered your downvote, but it probably happened because of the slew of deleted quality answers below.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused it, but it looks like the installer put the application in the wrong place (`C:\Program Files (x86)\` instead of `C:\Program Files\`) and set the registry paths wrong.

My solution was to completely uninstall, delete all related registry entries and then re-install. After that everything is working fine. I suspect a bug in the installer that is dependent on specific options being selected.

Answer (score 5):

Delete following entries With regedit from Run Menu:

1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui

After this Reinstall application it will come .

It works for me.

Alternate option is also to [change the registry manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20220510150332/https://www.hoverdroids.com/errors/git/git-gui-here-and-git-bash-here-doesnt-work-resolved/). Note, you don't actually need to download anything. Just open regedit, use Ctrl+F to find occurrences of "git_shell", and change the paths on each occurrence found, as well as on the sibling "git_gui" keys and their children "command" keys. Restart explorer.exe if needed.

Comment: Be sure to search for all occurrences. Just deleting it from that path didn't fix it for me. Uninstalling, deleting git_gui and git_shell from all paths in the registry then installing did.

Comment: The hoverdroids link shows a completely empty page. That is why it is recommended to copy solutions into the answer, so that they don't disappear like this.

Comment: @DavidBalažic You can view it at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20220510150332/https://www.hoverdroids.com/errors/git/git-gui-here-and-git-bash-here-doesnt-work-resolved/). I edited the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, you can go to your home drive (defined by %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH%, e.g. H:), or just run "Git Bash" (which will go straight to your home drive.

Create a .bash_profile file with the following:

```
# ------------ begin of script --------------
#!/bin/bash
target_drive=$(env | grep '!C:' | cut -d: -f3 | sed 's|\\|\/|g')
if [[ "${target_drive}" != "" ]]; then
    cd "/c/${target_drive}"
fi
# ------------ end of script --------------
```

save it and chmod 700 .bash_profile.

Then you can go to Windows explorer and right mouse click on a folder you try to run Git-Bash, it will switch to the folder.

The example above use C:. You can tweak it so it works for all drives.

Comment: I found the root cause of the problem. Please go to regedit:Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor. Check AutoRun. In my environment it has "cd /d H:\". After deleting that AutoRun the problem is gone. You don't need to fiddle with .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but different issue while taking a tutorial course on Pluralsight and trying to set up Git on Windows. I could not run `nvm use 8.11.2` in Git Bash (even running as administrator) because... who knows. It thought I did not have a default app installed for this. Luckily, the course administrator recommended using Windows CP if I ran into any "funkiness". CP was able to find a default app somewhere, apparently. Screenshot below.

[image: Run as administrator: Git Bash vs. Windows Command Prompt]