# scoop installed git bash: "Open Git Bash" here context menu

Tags: windows, git, registry, git-bash, scoop-installer

I have installed git via [Scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) on Windows 10 x64.

Using the detailed instruction from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44019893/374996) I created my own reg script, to add a "Open Git Bash" command in the context menu of Windows Explorer, for my own user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Git Bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\shims\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open Git Bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\shims\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\shims\\git-bash.exe"


[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\shims\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\shims\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\shims\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%v.\""
```

However, there are two problems with this:

### 1. Icon does not work

The icon within the context menu does not work:

[image: explorer context menu]

May be this is more of a scoop issue. I am not sure how scoop creates those shims.

### 2. Two git bash windows open

When I actually use the context menu option, two git bash windows open:

[image: opened git bash examples]

One with the actual git bash, and one that just says "git-bash.exe". Closing either window closes both windows.

Of course I'd like to have it as if I had downloaded and installed git directly from https://git-scm.com/download/win . May be someone has any insights on how to alleviate those issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`shim.exe`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/tree/master/supporting/shimexe) doesn't have an icon, so it can't be displayed.
In this case, it's recommended to use the `current` version path. (e.g. `~\scoop\apps\git\current\git-bash.exe`)

Change the icon path to:

```
[HKEY_USERS\user-sid\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\fritzmg\\scoop\\apps\\git\\current\\git-bash.exe"
```

Comment: Aaah, thank you, I have not noticed the `current` symlink within each app's directory :)