# Logon failed Even i entered the correct username and Password in git Bash?

Tags: git

I get:

```
 Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
 error: cannot spawn santhu@6218: No such file or directory
```

Even when I enter the correct username and Password, I am also facing error:

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
error: cannot spawn santhu@6218: No such file or directory
```

I also tried:

```
git config --global user.name "Enter Name"
git config --global user.name "Enter Email"
```

But no use. How can I get past this error message?

Comment: Can you add the OS version, Git version and Git command which triggers the error message?

Answer (score 0):

As [advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55768926/6309), make sure your Git is at the latest version (Windows: `git update-git-for-windows`, Linux: `git update`)

Note that `config user.name/user.email` has nothing to do with authentication (required for a clone/push/pull) and is only for local commit authorship.

Check if you have a credential helper set, which might have cached the wrong credentials.

```
git config credential.helper
```

And see if this error is on `git clone` or `git push` (in the latter case, that clone might have worked first)

Comment: git config credential. helper  No Use in my local machine  it well returns simply manger

Comment: @Santhosh OK. I left a comment above requesting the OS version, Git version and Git command  which triggers the error message: do you have those information?

Comment: @well returns simply "manger": I suppose "manager": that is an old credential helper. These days, you should see "manager-core". Again, I will wait for complementary information (you can edit your question to that effect)

Answer (score 0):

Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

So Please use a personal access token instead.

Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.

I was able to push my code to GIT only with personal access token.