# How to add "Git Bash Here" to an existing git installation

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

I don't want to lose any of my work. Is there a chance to make this the only setting?

I already checked some suggestions like registry editor:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell`

However, I don't have folder directories. My git-bash.exe file is located here:

```
C:\win64apps\Git
```

Comment: Just run the installer again and select the relevant option. I've done this many times and I've never encountered an issue.

Comment: Where is the installer? I only see in the folder git-bash.exe

Comment: Grab it from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Comment: do you need to login in the system with credentials when you install it again?

Comment: I am afraid that i will need to set my repos again

Comment: You won't. Git Bash is a program that's installed on your system. Your git repositories are _data_ that's on your system. It's like updating an app on your phone, you don't loose all your pictures and messages etc.

Comment: Well, it worked with the installer, thank you so much, nothing is deleted and no passwords needed!

Comment: You can found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39194769/8039744

Answer (score 0):

Summarising from comments;

If you run the Git Bash installer again (which you can download from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win)) you'll be able to select the relevant option.

Your existing repositories won't be affected. You'll just be using the latest and greatest version of Git Bash with new features and bug fixes.